# Why parent component change when child change a value in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm working with Angular 4, I have a ParentComponent and a ChildComponent like this

```
class ParentComponent {
   private propertyParent:object

   ngOnInit(){
     this.propertyParent={
       name: 'Name'
     }
   }
}    

class ChildComponent {
   @input private propertyChild:object

   ngOnInit(){         
   }
} 

<parent-component>
   <child-component [propertyChild]="propertyParent">
   </child-component>
</parent-component>
```

I have a question, when change propertyChild in ChildComponent the value of propertyParent in ParentComponent is changing. Is it correct that changes in child component affect to propertyParent?

Comment: Yes, this is the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the expected outcome.

```js
var hello = {
  example: "an example"
};

var t = hello;

t.example = "yawn";

console.log(hello, t);
```

This is because when you assign an object in this fashion, you are basically creating 2 pointers to the same memory allocation i.e the original object.

Here is an angular example that proves you do not need 2 way binding for this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jj6mnj

Comment: So, i don't need to use two data-binding ... ?

Comment: @yussenn I have added a working example which DOES NOT require 2 way binding.